# How to find solutions more than one in a function in R?

Tags: r

I have just started to study with R and I could not find any solution to this simple problem. I tried to create my own function.

```
sta<-function(a)
```

`{mean1<-mean(data$feb05, na.rm = TRUE)` 
`var(data$feb05, na.rm = TRUE)}`

In the function, my aim is find to mean and variance of the data. The problems I encountered are:

1) I wanted to give `mean1` name to mean of data. But whenever I write mean1 I can't get any solution.

2)If I write only `mean(data$feb05, na.rm = TRUE)` in the function without name and var function I can obtain the solution. But If I write mean and var together, I can't get any solution.

So as a summary, I am asking for giving a name to solution, and finding more than one solution in one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return it as a vector

```
sta <- function(a) {
   c(mean1 = mean(a, na.rm = TRUE),  var1 = var(a, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

and now you can do

```
sta(data$feb05)
```

For example,

```
new_var <- sta(mtcars$mpg)
new_var
#mean1  var1 
#   20    36
```

So if you want to access individual elements now, you can do

```
new_var['mean1']
#mean1 
#   20 

new_var['var1']
#var1 
#  36
```

Or you can also return them as a `list`

```
sta <- function(a) {
  list(mean1 = mean(a, na.rm = TRUE),  var1 = var(a, na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

and use the `$` operator to access elements like `new_var$mean1` and `new_var$var1`.

Comment: Also I wonder, is it possible to transfer this result to data section within function. Without function I could transfer mean1 result to data, but when I write the same function in the function, it did not work.
So, I want to see mean1 and var1 results as a data or value

Comment: @HüsamettinTayşi If by data you mean dataframe, then you can convert the function to `sta <- function(a) {
  data.frame(mean1 = mean(a, na.rm = TRUE),  var1 = var(a, na.rm = TRUE))
}` and it will return you a dataframe instead of vector.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHJAB.jpg I mean like in the pic, after running of function, I want to see new_var in data section automatically, or I want to see ''mean'' automatically as a value. Sorry for my phrase, I hope I could express myself.

Comment: If you do `new_var <- sta(mtcars$mpg)` you should see `new_var` in the data section automatically. Works for me.